# Combining multiple text files with same header format using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple text files I need to combine

[image: Example text file]

All have the same headers (with the exception of the Image name, but this will change in ascending order, with "HU1284 - Position 2.Blind", "HU1284 - Position 3.Blind" etc), but varying numbers of rows of information within their dataset. I've been using an excel macro to combine them, but this requires separating each file in the program that generates the text files, and that takes ages. I'm trying to avoid that if possible. Would anyone be able to help me modify the VBA script below so that it can combine these text files as is? Thanks in advance!!

```
Public HeadLine As String
Public ThisLine As String
Public Checkfilenum
Public TotalRows
Public NDresults

Sub Comb_1()
' Comb_1 Macro Used to combine the text files together into a sindle result file if new data results
' in going over the row limit then attempt will be made to make a new dresult file by incrementing index.
' will loop through until a valid dresults file can be made.

nbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'checkfor opened dresults workbook
wcnt = 0
For Each w In Workbooks
If UCase(w.Name) Like "DRESULT*" Then
wcnt = 1
w.Activate
End If
Next
If wcnt = 1 And HeadLine = "FirstOne" Then HeadLine = ThisLine
    
' CHeck if adding new file will exceed 65536 limit of Excel (may need to change for 2007)
Call MaxNumRowscheck(nbook, wcnt)
' If dresults file is not opened then create it from thie file (nbook)
If wcnt = 0 Then
    'Check if this is the first file in this run so we have line 6 to compare against.
    If HeadLine = "FirstOne" Then HeadLine = ThisLine
    On Error GoTo exitsub
    ' create dresults (note will check for existance of one just in case.)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="dresults.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlNormal
    Workbooks("dresults.xlsm").Activate
    ' prep sheet
    Sheets(1).Name = "Combined data"
    
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
        "_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A3"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A4").Select
   
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
    Range("G1:J1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Rows("1:6").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Range("A2:E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Exp_Round"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Within_Round_Pair"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Within_Pair_Imaged_Seq"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Image_Number"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Mask"
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
ElseIf ThisLine = HeadLine Then
    ' repeat work above but for files just being prepared and appended
    ' using the previously started dresults file
```

Comment: "Would anyone be able to help me modify the VBA script below so that it can combine these text files as is" - what do you mean by "as is" here?  What is different in the "as is" output?  Is all of the instrument data in a single file vs one file per image?  It's not clear exactly what change you want to make.  Also not clear what conditions your posted code runs under  -all of the input files are already open or ?

Comment: Thank you for your response and request for more data. I believe I have finally gotten it figured out, but I appreciate your intent to help!